# ÅÄÖ in Site Design script

Tags: site, design, site-design, site-script

I have a super simple site design script that supposed to remove left nav links. One of the links contain the character "å" (swedish letter). But sharepoint doesn't recognize this letter and it shows "Ã¥". I guess this has something with the character encoding. Anyone knows how to fix this so Sharepoint recognize the letter? The code looks like this:

```
{
     "$schema": "schema.json",
         "actions": [
             {
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Pages",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Conversations",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Site Contents",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Konversationer",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Sidor",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "'Webbplatsinnehåll'",
    "isWebRelative": true
}
                 ]
             }
         ],
             "bindata": { },
     "version": 1
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it! Did it by adding -Encoding UTF-8 like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\PATH\Site Designs\poc_site_design.json' -Raw -Encoding UTF8 | Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "POC Site design"
```